# Asp.net Web API - Where to Save Custom Handlers?

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I just started to get into ASP.net Web API (created MVC 4 project, Web API application, in .net 4.5).

I need to make custom handlers in particular. All I know is that we create one (inherit DelegatingHandler), and register it in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs's Register function.

Where do we save such a handler (`MyMessageHandler`), though? No tutorial or book I've come tells me this. I tried to save it in the App_Start folder with the same namespace as WebApiConfig, but it says that `MyMessageHandler` cannot be found:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyMessageHandler()); // MyMessageHandler is not found.
```

Comment: OK. This is really strange - I deleted MyMessageHandler.cs and recreated it from scratch exactly as how it was. Now, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Where you store MyMessageHandler.cs doesn't matter at all, as long as you get your references in `WebApiConfig` right. I personally store them like `project_root/MessageHandlers/MyMessageHandler.cs`